# UpdateMany in mongoose not working but directly in mongodb works fine

Tags: node.js, mongodb, typescript, mongoose, nestjs

I'm trying to make update/insert in **mongoose**. I make some request and the result is ( exemple )

```
let obj = [
    {name: aaa,age: 10},
    {name: bbb,age: 11},
    {name: ccc,age: 12},
]
```

I'm trying to update all documents, but if they dont exist, create them.

I tried do:

```
updateMany({}, {$set: {nome:"obj.$.name", idade: "obj.$.age"}}, {upsert:true})
```

But, nothing happens, I try to make another test in mongoose, more simple, like this:

```
<model-context>.updateMany({},{$set: {name: 'abc'}},{upsert: true})
```

Didnt work, so I make the same update direct in mongodb

```
db.context.updateMany({},{$set: {name: 'abc'}},{upsert: true})
```

And worked, I need to do something more in mongoose to work?

**NOTE**: I can use createMany in mongoose, works fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved the problem, i need to pass a function in argument of updateMany

```
for(let n of obj){
   <context>.update({name: n.name}, {$set: {'age':n.age}}, {upsert: true},  
(err, doc)=>{
    if(err) console.log(err);
    console.log(doc)
 })
}
```

Comment: Actually, you abandoned the updateMany. But, if you wanna go back to the updateMany, see that you need to pass a condition to the criteria when using upsert, because mongoose needs to evaluate if it is going to update or insert. In your first attempt, you were not passing the criteria to the query.

Comment: Did you set a criteria?

Comment: This is not bulk updating so will not scale.